# Prove that $m$ is ergodic.

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space, $f\colon X\rightarrow X$ be a function. Suppose that there exists a unique invariant Borel probability measure $m$. Prove that $m$ is ergodic.

Thank you.

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people are much more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, many would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Prove..."), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: Thank you so much Zev for your advice. So $X$ is any topological space and $f$ is a function from it to itself. There exists a unique invariant borel probability measure m. I need to show that m is ergodic. Now I have assumed by contradiction that m is not ergodic. Then we have $A$ measurable such that $T^(-1)(A)=A$ but $0<m(A)>1$. I dont know how to proceed from here. I think somehow I need to contradict the uniqueness of the measure m. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I meant $T^(-1)(A)=A$ and $0<m(A)<1$.

Comment: So I guess $T=f$.

Answer (score 6):

So assume $m$ is not ergodic, so that there exists an invariant measurable set $A$ such that
$$
0<m(A)<1.
$$

Now consider the following two measures
$$
m_1(B):=\frac{m(A\cap B)}{m(A)}\quad\mbox{and}\quad m_2(B)=\frac{m(A^c\cap B)}{1-m(A)}
$$
where $A^c=X\setminus A$.

Observe that these are two invariant Borel probability measures.

By assumption, they must be equal.

But
$$
m_1(A)=1\neq 0=m_2(A).
$$

So $m$ is ergodic.

Comment: @adtx11 You're welcome. Since you seem to be new over here, don't forget that if you like an answer, you can upvote, and even accept it if it really pleases you.