# Need help in proving a unique invariant borel probability measure is ergodic.

Tags: ergodic-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space and $f : X \rightarrow X$ be a function. Suppose that there exists a unique invariant borel probability measure m. We need show that m is ergodic :  I assumed by contradiction that m is not ergodic. Then there is $A$ measurable such that $f^{-1}(A)=A$ and $0 < m(A) < 1$. How do I go from here?? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have already asked this question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305769/prove-that-m-is-ergodic, and it has even been answered. Maybe you could delete this one?

Comment: Yes Julien, I can definitely delete this one, but I am sorry to say that I do not know how to delete a question here; I cannot find any delele link anywhere.